# Ngx spinner is blocking whole page using Angular

Tags: css, angular, ngx-spinner

I am implementing `ngx-spinner` in my application using Angular but the issue is I need it to load on specific area of the page but it blocking entire page. I am explaining my code below.

```
<p> Hello name </p>
<div class="content" style="margin-top: 55px;">
    <div style="position: relative">
      <ngx-spinner bdColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)" size = "medium" color = "#fff" type = "square-jelly-box" [fullScreen] = "true"><p style="color: white" > Loading... </p></ngx-spinner>
    </div>
    <cui-modal></cui-modal>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

Here I need to load the spinner inside the `<div class="content" style="margin-top: 55px;"></div>` only means the contents inside this div will be blocked but its blocking the entire screen. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: create a fiddle with dependencies

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7arfhb

Answer (score 1):

I follow your description and created a stackblitz example, I found maybe just input is wrong?

I found the document has this configuration.
https://github.com/Napster2210/ngx-spinner
Just set `fullScreen` false can avoid spinner cover the whole page.

```
Fullscreen Mode(Enable/Disable)
```

This is my partial template code.

```html
    <ngx-spinner
          bdColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)"
          size="medium"
          color="#fff"
          type="square-jelly-box"
          [fullScreen]="false"
          ><p style="color: white">Loading...</p>
    </ngx-spinner>
```

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbcrve?file=src/app/app.component.html